# django admin login error: A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, admin, environment

I am trying to set up my admin environment but keep getting this stupid server error on my Chrome browser:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

So far I have only created a new app ("mainpage") with following model:

```
from django.db import models

class num_of_packs(models.Model):
    number_field= models.CharField(max_length=3, default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.number_field
```

and I have set up all neccesary databases + added "mainpage" to the global settings in:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'mainpage.apps.MainpageConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Then I have set up the superuser succesfully and booted the server.

Anyone know a fix for it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more detail. Show your work. What have you tried? What are the steps to reproduce what you've done.

Comment: I have just setup the superuser. The process finished succesfully. I have created one test app + model, I have set up the databases for all apps. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: the  `'django.contrib.admin'` in  `INSTALLED_APPS` hasnt been changed either

Comment: Please edit the original question and mention all of this. Also include where you're seeing this error (command line, browser, etc.). etc.

Comment: Alright, I think I have added everything neccesary. @Soviut

Comment: do you have debug enabled in settings?

Comment: Yes my debug is `DEBUG = True`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

First, put your imported app last in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list since it will rely on previous apps to work properly.

Second, your model isn't following the Django convention. Models are classes and should be named with camel case, starting with an uppercase letter (eg: `NumberOfPacks`) and don't put `_field` in your field names. This convention matters because it's what Django uses to display friendly class names in the admin.

Additionally, you should really read up on data modeling, because the way you're storing your data and naming your fields is not very conducive. You typically model your data as collections of things, like `User`, `Profile`, `BlogPost`, or in your case, `Pack`. You'd then associate 3 distinct Pack models with a User model via a foreign key relationship. You'd then simply be able to count how many packs a user had by counting the relationships.

Third, you need to make sure you migrate your models from the command line otherwise their associated tables won't exist in the database. Each time you update your models you have to make migrations and then run those migrations.

Comment: Alright I will go try it out, I am used to naming everything very specifically, since thats how I name it when writing scripts in Python. Thanks for the words of wisdom, I will let you know if I have progressed. Cheers

Comment: Alright, unfortunatelly the error is still popping up. I have renamed everything, moved the APP down and ran "makemigrations". I now get this error in cmd `File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`